# how to identify client sockets to remote servers opened during program execution

Tags: networking

I have a certain build process and I want to ensure that no external system is accessed during that build so I can be sure that I am not relying on anything external to my organization. Rather than bringing the interface down, is there some monitoring tool I could use to see which client sockets a given process is opening?

I've thought of using `strace` and grepping for `recvfrom`. Indeed I don't see anything there. Would that suffice to prove the point? Is there some better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linux [namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html) to isolate the build process from the network.  The [`unshare`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html) command can be used to do this simply.  However, that will also prevent the build process from connecting to the localhost via TCP/IP.  To let the build process *only* connect to localhost is a bit more complicated, detailed [here](http://abregman.com/2016/09/29/linux-network-namespace/).

Note that all of the above will require root access.  If you want the build process to run as a normal user, you can make the command to be run in the namespace be `su build-user -c build-command`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following:

```
strace -s 1000 -e trace=network build-command
```